Sit Game Window Above The Taskbar
I am trying to make a windowed transparent game in unity. I figured out how to make an transparent game but I want to make game window sit the task bar.
I tried out change y value in SetWindowPos function but it didn't worked. It would be great if someone show me how to do it.
Here is my code:
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; // Pro and Free!!!


public class TransparentWindow : MonoBehaviour
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLongA")]
    static extern int SetWindowLong(int hwnd, int nIndex, long dwNewLong);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(int hWnd, int nCmdShow);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetLayeredWindowAttributes")]
    static extern int SetLayeredWindowAttributes(int hwnd, int crKey, byte bAlpha, uint dwFlags);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetActiveWindow")]
    private static extern int GetActiveWindow();
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowLong")]
    private static extern long GetWindowLong(int hwnd, int nIndex);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowPos")]
    private static extern int SetWindowPos(int hwnd, int hwndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, int uFlags);

    const uint LWA_COLORKEY = 0x00000001; 
    const int HWND_TOPMOST = -1;

    void Start()
    {
        int handle = GetActiveWindow();
        int fWidth = Screen.width;
        int fHeight = Screen.height / 10;

        //Remove title bar
        long lCurStyle = GetWindowLong(handle, -16);  // GWL_STYLE=-16
        int a = 12582912;  //WS_CAPTION = 0x00C00000L
        int b = 1048576;  //WS_HSCROLL = 0x00100000L
        int c = 2097152;  //WS_VSCROLL = 0x00200000L
        int d = 524288;  //WS_SYSMENU = 0x00080000L
        int e = 16777216;  //WS_MAXIMIZE = 0x01000000L

        lCurStyle &= ~(a | b | c | d);
        lCurStyle &= e;
        SetWindowLong(handle, -16, lCurStyle);// GWL_STYLE=-16

        // Transparent windows with click through
        SetWindowLong(handle, -20, 524288);//GWL_EXSTYLE=-20; WS_EX_LAYERED=524288=&h80000,           WS_EX_TRANSPARENT=32=0x00000020L
        SetLayeredWindowAttributes(handle, 0, 0, LWA_COLORKEY);// Transparency=51=20%, LWA_ALPHA=2
        SetWindowPos(handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0,0, fWidth, fHeight, 32 | 64); //SWP_FRAMECHANGED = 0x0020 (32); //SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040 (64)
        Screen.SetResolution(fWidth, fHeight, true);
        ShowWindowAsync(handle, 3); //Forces window to show in case of unresponsive app  // SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED(3)
    }
}


You are setting your window to be at location 0, 0 on the screen, with a height of Screen.height / 10. So what is that value and how does it relate to the height of the taskbar?
